# when I launch a sweep scan launchfile, failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
$ roslaunch sweep_ros sweep2scan.launch 


[ERROR] [1510555966.860890582]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
```

I dont know why.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275713/when-i-launch-a-sweep-scan-launchfile,-failed/) by [wings0728](https://answers.ros.org/users/32538/wings0728/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2017-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known issue with the latest `gmapping` release and should be fixed in the next release.

See [ros-perception/slam_gmapping#56](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/pull/56) and #q274849.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0